# Etimología de "Bolsa de consorcio"

Tags: etimología, argentina

En Argentina, he usado la oración "bolsa de consorcio" para referirme a una bolsa negra de basura grande ([todas estos imágenes ilustran bolsa de consorcio](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=bolsa%20de%20consorcio&tbm=isch)) toda mi vida sin reflexionar en su significado.

Recientemente me di cuenta que "consorcio" suele significar, en Argentina al menos, un complejo de varios departamentos, o un edificio donde viven varias personas o hay varios negocios que comparten un tacho de basura. ¿Me imagino que de ahí viene llamarle "bolsa de consorcio"? No se me ocurre otra posibilidad.

Buscando en Google "bolsa de consorcio" y "etimología de bolsa de consorcio", no obtuve ningún resultado que hiciera referencia a eso. Les pido que me ayuden.

Answer (score 4):

En los edificios de varios departamentos, típicamente el "encargado del consorcio" (portero o asistente de limpieza, contratado por el consorcio) se encarga de recolectar las bolsas individuales de basura de cada departamento, y colocarlas en una o varias bolsas grandes para sacarlas a la calle. Ese tipo de bolsa (grande, generalmente negra), se empezó  a llamar "bolsa de consorcio" (algo así como "bolsa que usa el encargado del consorcio" o "bolsa para uso del consorcio", como opuesta a la bolsa pequeña para uso individual). Al menos eso supongo.

Comment: Ok. No me salia La frase "edificio de varios departamentos" gracias por eso. Una pregunta, En tú respuesta, La bolsa de consorcio sería La grande del portero, o La de cada depto?

Comment: Supongo que "bolsa de consorcio" se empezó a usar para las grandes que usaba el portero, pero luego se extendió a bolsas grandes, aunque sean para uso individual.

Comment: Ah ok, pero yo te pregunto específicamente En tú respuesta. Pues entonces tú respuesta hay 2 tipos de bolsas. ( Igual, puede ser que como decís ahora se extendió a toda bolsa grande.) Quería saber tú intención En el post original.

Comment: Creo que la suposición es correcta. Yo generalmente digo *bolsa de basura* para referirme a las bolsas negras que uno compra por docena para tirar la basura, pero *de consorcio* también lo uso y entiendo. La ventaja de esta última es que decir *bolsa de basura* es ambiguo ya que una bolsa común que uso para juntar basura también entra dentro de los significados.